# mget to transfer multiple files from multiple subdirectories

Tags: regex, linux, ftp, subdirectory

I need some help with an efficiency problem I am having using **NcFTP**. I'm open to using other **FTP** programs, if another suits this task better.

I need to **FTP** into a remote server, change to a directory on the remote server where the sub directories for the files I need are located.

Once in the parent directory of all the sub-directories, I am currently having to

- cd into each sub-directory where the text files are,
- execute 'get file.txt'.
- then 'cd ..' up
- then repeat for the next sub-directory

What I would like to do is use regexps and one command line argument to accomplish the task.  There are regexp patterns for the files in each directory which are similar to:

```
/parent_directory/file_1/file_1.txt
/parent_directory/file_2/file_2.txt
.
.
.
/parent_directory/file_n/file_n.txt
```

I can develop the **regexp** no problem. Just cant figure out the syntax of accomplishing this in one line.  The files may appear in the local working directory with the original filenames.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I made significant edits to the format of your question to improve readability. Generally, actual HTML is not needed within a question's format. Also `The files need not be in any certain subdirectory on the local machine.`, you may need to clarify this. While the courtesies (Aloha, Thank you) are nice, they're not part of the general question format). Stack Exchange is more about getting directly down to business. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

from the parent directory -

> mget file1/file1.* file2/file2.* ... fileN/fileN